# how to show error message on struts2 jquery dialog box

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery

I have a form open in Struts2 jquery dialog box. When users submit this form, i want to show the Server Side error message *(eg. Username exist,Please choose another)*  on this same open  dialoguebox itself .

How can i do this? Any hint or suggestion!  Please share.

index.jsp (on click of a button the below form will open)

```
`<s:actionerror/>
 <s:form action="testError" id="form3" theme="simple"/> 
     <s:textfield name="quantity" value="1""/>
 <s:form> 
 <sj:submit formId="form3" value="true"/>`
```

Action.java

```
public String execute()
{   
     addActionError("Error message is blah blah");
      return ERROR;
    }
```

Struts.xml

```
<action name="testError" class="com.Action">  
 <result name="error">index.jsp</result> 
</action>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<s:if test="hasErrors()">
    <sj:dialog title="error message">
        <s:actionerror/>
    </sj:dialog>
</s:if>
```